# python class attribute

Tags: python, class, attributes

i have a question about class attribute in python.

```
class base :
    def __init__ (self):
        pass
    derived_val = 1

t1 = base()
t2 = base()

t2.derived_val +=1
t2.__class__.derived_val +=2
print t2.derived_val             # its value is 2
print t2.__class__.derived_val   # its value is 3
```

The results are different. I also use `id()` function to find `t2.derived_val` and `t2.__class__.derived_val` have different memory address.
My problem is `derived_val` is class attribute. Why it is different in above example?
Is it because the instance of class copy its own `derived_val` beside the class attribute?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

There are class attributes, and instance attributes.
When you say

```
class base :
    derived_val = 1
```

You are defining a class attribute. `derived_val` becomes a key in
`base.__dict__`.

```
t2=base()
print(base.__dict__)
# {'derived_val': 1, '__module__': '__main__', '__doc__': None}
print(t2.__dict__)
# {}
```

When you say `t2.derived_val` Python tries to find 'derived_val' in `t2.__dict__`. Since it is not there, it looks if there is a `'derived_val'` key in any of `t2`'s base classes.

```
print(t2.derived_val)
print(t2.__dict__)
# 1
# {}
```

But when you assign a value to `t2.derived_val`, you are now adding an instance attribute to `t2`. A `derived_val` key is added to `t2.__dict__`.

```
t2.derived_val = t2.derived_val+1
print(t2.derived_val)
print(t2.__dict__)
# 2
# {'derived_val': 2}
```

Note that at this point, there are two `derived_val` attributes, but only
the instance attribute is easily accessible. The class attribute becomes accessible only through referencing `base.derived_val` or direct access to the class dict `base.__dict__`.

Comment: Is this a defect? I don't remember c++ but isn't it supposed to hold on to its ID (I mean to the same object). Why did the `derived_val` got added to t2.__dict__? You didn't do something like t2['derived_val'] = value.

Answer (score 4):

Check it out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68645/static-class-variables-in-python) and [here](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html).

The `__class__` attribute is the class that the object belongs to.  So in your example, the situation is similar to static variables.  The `t2.__class__.derived_val` is referring to the variable that belongs to the class, not the variable that belongs to t2.

Answer (score 4):

Another way (perhaps a more concise one) to demonstrate this:

```
class A():
   a1 = []
x = A()
y = A()
x.a1.append("test")
x.a1, y.a1
(['test'], ['test'])

class B():
   b1 = None
   def __init__(self):
      self.b1 = list()
r = B()
s = B()
r.b1.append("test")
r.b1, s.b1
(["test"], [])
```