# Class attribute for two instances of the same class

Tags: python

There is this code:

```
class Sample:
    variable = 2
object1 = Sample()
object2 = Sample()
print object1.variable  # 2
print object2.variable  # 2
object1.variable = 1
print object1.variable  # 1
print object2.variable  # 2 <- why not 1 too?
```

Why *object2.variable* is not also 1 after assignment to class variable?

Comment: possible duplicate of [python class attribute](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2923579/python-class-attribute)

Comment: For my understanding im asking this only: what was the thinking behind the question? Isn't it obvious that object1 & object2 are distinct instances of the same class?

Comment: I think he believes that `variable` is static because it's defined outside of a function, or something like this. Not sure really :) Still a reasonable question somehow.

Comment: @hochl: +1 for the "somehow" :D

Comment: it is reassigned. Use a mutable datastructure (like a dictionary) to get the expected behaviour.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't confuse this with a static variable. In your case, both objects have a name `variable` point to a `2` object after instantiation. Now if you change the variable to `1` in one object, all you do is bind the `name` to a different object, i.e. the `1` object. The name in object2 still refers to a `2` object. The original class object is untouched and still has the name `variable` point to a `2`, so `object3 = Sample()` will have a `2` bound to `variable` as well.

One way to get around this is to write the class like the following:

```
>>> class Sample:
...     variable=[2]
... 
>>> object1 = Sample()
>>> object2 = Sample()
>>> print object1.variable[0]; print object2.variable[0]
2
2
>>> object1.variable[0]=1
>>> print object1.variable[0]; print object2.variable[0]
1
1
```

This is because all classes bind the name `variable` to the same, *muatable* object, and you manipulate the contents of this same object (`variable[0]`).

Answer (score 4):

Because you assign new instance variable into instance, not class variable. If you can change class attribute, then you must set variable through `__class__` attribute. (Or directly to class object.)

```
class Sample:
    variable = 2
object1 = Sample()
object2 = Sample()
print object1.variable  # 2
print object2.variable  # 2
object1.__class__.variable = 1 # or Sample.variable = 1
print object1.variable  # 1
print object2.variable  # 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68645/static-class-variables-in-python).

In a nutshell, your class and your class instance have different namespaces (Actually, this is not very correct because instance namespace kinda places on top of class' namespace so that in case if you have a class atribute and an instance attribute with the same name, instance' one will be accessed through `inst.attr` , otherways - class' one). So, when you do

```
object1.variable = 1
```

you do not actually change class variable (which is often called static field in other languages), you just *bind a new field* called `variable` to your *class instance* `object1`.

What you probably want to do is to change class variable, not instance one. It could be done like this:

```
Sample.variable = 1
```

or like this:

```
object1.__class__.variable = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Two instances of a same class don't share the same memory and the same variables. For instance, you can have a `Car` whose `color` is `red` and another whose color is `blue`.

Answer (score 1):

You've answered the question in the title. They are two separate and distinct **instances** of the same class. `object1` and `object2` are different objects and therefore anything that happens to one of these objects will not alter the other.

Comment: that’s not quite true (though valid for simple attribute assignments). As soon as you have mutable data structures, the instances are connected.

Answer (score 1):

Because object1 is a different object than object2. To have them be the same, you need to do

```
class Sample:
  variable = 2
object1 = Sample()
object2 = object1
print object1.variable
print object2.variable
object1.variable = 1
print object1.variable
print object2.variable
```

Note the line that says

```
object2 = object1
```

Answer (score 1):

This is perhaps counterintuitive, but when you write

```
object1.variable = 1
```

You're not assigning to the class variable, but defining an instance variable of the same name. (You can inspect `object1`'s `__dict__` to verify this). Notice that if you write

```
Sample.variable
```

or

```
object1.__class__.variable
```

You'll get `2` in both cases, because `variable` was never actually changed. To assign to it, you can refer to it as above -- `object1.__class__.variable = 1`, for instance, makes it so that `object2.variable == 1` also.