# Doing something to one object does the same to all objects of the same class?

Tags: python, class, oop, variables, object

I'm only just starting to actually dabble seriously in Python, so it's possible this has a very easy answer, but at the moment I'm just dumbfounded. Here's the gist of what my code is:

```
class deck:
    cards = [
        'ace of spades',
        'two of spades',
        'three of spades',
    ] #...and so on


    def deal(self, hand): #takes the last card in the deck and transfers it to the supplied hand
        hand.add_card(self.cards.pop(-1))

class hand:
    cards = []

    def add_card(self, card):
        self.cards.append(card)

foobar = deck()
hand1 = hand()
hand2 = hand()
foobar.deal(hand1)
print(hand2.cards) #['three of spades']
```

What I want is to be able to deal a card from the deck to a hand, by calling `deck.deal(hand)`.

The good news is, the above code does indeed take a card from `foobar` and add it to `hand1`. The bad news is... it also adds it to `hand2`.

This is probably the most confused I've ever been from programming. `hand1` and `hand2` are *quite clearly two distinct variables*! So why does dealing a card to one hand also deal the same card to the other hand? I mean, the only time `hand2` is even mentioned is when it's being created.

Comment: possible duplicate of [python class attribute](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2923579/python-class-attribute)

Comment: Actually, more a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/207000/python-difference-between-class-and-instance-attributes.  It might help you to check out the answers to the linked question, Cal.

Comment: first you need to learn the difference between a class and an object. You are using classes as if they were objects. You need to instantiate the classes and create objects for the deck(s) and the hand(s). Pythonwise, `cards`, as they appear in both classes, are class attributes, not instance attributes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you wrote `cards = []` in the body of your `hand` class. This makes it a **class variable**, which is shared between all instances of the class (in your case, `hand1` and `hand2` are two different **instances** of the `hand` class). If any instance changes it, it will be reflected automatically in all other instances.

To create an **instance variable** in a class, which belongs to a single instance only, you should instead create a constructor inside your `hand` class which initializes `self.cards` like this:

```
def __init__(self):
    self.cards = []
```

An accessible introduction to instance and class variables is available in the [Object-Oriented Programming](http://www.python-course.eu/python3_object_oriented_programming.php) (subsection "Instance Variables") and [Class and Instance Variables](http://www.python-course.eu/python3_class_and_instance_attributes.php) chapters at Python Course. The official documentation regarding class and instance variables is in sections [9.3.2](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#class-objects) and [9.3.3](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#instance-objects), respectively, of the Python documentation.

Comment: This is because the code in the body is executed at class definition, not at object instantiation, so the object is created only once (then then shared between all instances)

Answer (score 1):

You need to create an instance variable, not a class variable:

```
class hand:
    def __init__(self):
        self.cards = []
```