# Why a classmethod can change the value of a class variable for one instance but not for another instance?

Tags: python

I have changed the value of class variable `raise_amount` for one instance. Later I have changed the value of the class variable with the classmethod `set_raise_amt` but it could not change the value for that particular instance, even though for the other instance it was changed. It's probably a noob question, but please help me understand.

```
class Employee:
    """
    A class that keeps employee records
    """
    raise_amount = 1.04

    def __init__(self, first, last):
        self.first = first
        self.last = last

    @classmethod
    def set_raise_amt(cls, amount):
        cls.raise_amount = amount


emp_1 = Employee("Test1", "Title1")
emp_2 = Employee("Test2", "Title2")

emp_1.raise_amount = 1.07
Employee.set_raise_amt(1.09)
Employee.raise_amount = 1.09

print(Employee.raise_amount)
print(emp_1.raise_amount)
print(emp_2.raise_amount)
```

The output is

```
1.09
1.07
1.09
[Finished in 0.084s]
```

Comment: Did you mean to use `emp_2.set_raise_amount`? Calling `Employee.set_raise_amount` is not tied to an instance?

Comment: `emp_1.raise_amount = 1.07` creates an instance attribute for `emp_1`.  You didn't define any such instance attribute for `emp_2`, so when you access `emp_2.raise_amount`, you get the corresponding class attribute.

Comment: Thank you to everyone for clearing it.

Comment: The question was linked as a duplicate did not answer this question. Which seems to be "Why is assigning to `self.attr` different to `cls.attr`?"

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2923579/python-class-attribute appears to be a better duplicate

Answer (score 2):

You are having a conflict between a class variable and an instance variable. When you call `emp_1.raise_amount = 1.07`, you are creating an instance variable with the same name as your class variable, and python always solves it this way:

> [If the same attribute name occurs in both an instance and in a class,
> then attribute lookup prioritizes the instance](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#random-remarks)

so `emp_1.raise_amount` will always refer the instance variable over the class one.

Answer (score 0):

You did not "change it" for `emp_1`. You created the instance member. Therefore, when asking for `emp_1.raise_amount`, the instance member value is returned, whereas `emp_2.raise_amount` is the class member.

Answer (score -1):

Use @staticmethod instead of @classmethod :

```
@staticmethod
def set_raise_amt(amount):
    Employee.raise_amount = amount
```

Comment: As this explicitely modifies a class attribute, this should rather be a class method (which would then get the class as first argument), not a static method. It should rather be written as `@classmethod   def set_raise_amt(cls, amount): cls.raise_amount = amount`

Comment: The problem is the call `emp_1.raise_amount=1.07`, which creates a new instance variable with the same name as the class variable, so it doesn't matter how you define the method, the result will be the same.